# PHP not displaying any errors

Tags: php, error-reporting

I know this has been asked multiple times in the past but none of the solutions worked for me.

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
  function
?>
```

This should produce an error. However, it's just returning a 500 error and not loading.

I tried less severe error producing code like this:

```
<?php
  $test = $example;
?>
```

Calling on an undefined variable produced an error on a different computer.

In my `php.ini`, I have `display_errors = On`, `display_startup_errors = On`, and `error_reporting = E_ALL`.

**Edit** Thanks to aspiringCodingArtisan's suggestion, I realized I was editing the wrong `php.ini` file. Problem solved.

Comment: If you check in your server logs, you'll see the error in detail there.

Comment: Is your error-producing `function` in your code, intentional in order to see the errors? And have you tried `error_reporting(E_ALL);` having `E_ALL` inside parentheses instead of `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `ini_set('display_errors',1);` ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's in their `php.ini` file so the `prop = value` syntax is correct

Comment: @Phil Ok, I thought that in not having `E_ALL` without parentheses would be invalid.

Comment: Create a `<?php phpinfo() ?>` file and check everything there. Check what values are set for `error_reporting` and `display_errors` as well as the location of your `php.ini` file and any other config files that may have been loaded. Duplicate properties will take the latter value so your settings may be getting overwritten.

Comment: What does `var_dump(ini_get('display_errors'));` output? Also make sure you're editing the correct `php.ini` file. You can check the location with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.

Comment: Are you looking at the correct `php.ini` file? If you have something like `MAMP` you will find that it has multiple versions of PHP.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP solved it already

Comment: @Phil: That doesn't mean it's off-topic; instead, it means they should post an answer with their solution and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking at the correct `php.ini` file? If you have something like MAMP you will find that it has multiple versions of PHP.